# MVC4: Assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I am new to MVC so bear with a little disorientation please. I have a .NET 4.5 solution with the following projects:

- Parkalot.Entity (Contains entity classes)
- Parkalot.Database (Contains data context classes)
- Parkalot.Mvc4AspxClient (The web client)

All projects have been configured with EntityFramework 5 using NuGet and all projects target .NET 4.5. All are set to Any CPU. Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Preview on 64 Bit Winddows 8 Pro (not that it should matter).

If I try to use the data context to access the database from the Global.asax of the web client, it works fine so no issues up to the point of the web client.

When adding controllers, as long as I select the `[Empty MVC Controller]` template, it works fine. When I try to add a controller with template type `[MVC Controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework]` and select an Parkalot.Entity.Tenant as the model class and Parkalot.Database.Context as the data context class I get the following error:

```
Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Parkalot.Entity.Tenant'. Could not load file or assembly
'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or 
one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the 
assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

In case it is related, I also get the following compile-time warning:

```
C:\...\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1613,5): warning MSB3247:
    Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.
    Please add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in your
    application configuration file:

     - Parkalot.Mvc4AspxClient ->
        C:\...Parkalot.Mvc4AspxClient\bin\Parkalot.Mvc4AspxClient.dll
```

The solution was originally created in VS2010, then upgraded to VS 2013 and .NET 4.5. I wonder if that is the cause but still have no idea how to fix it.

**EDIT:** When searching for version 4.4.0.0 as the error indicates, I found the following!

```
C:\...\Parkalot.WinFormsClient\App.config(5):
 - <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
C:\...\Parkalot.WinFormsClient\Visual Studio\app.config(5):
 - <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
C:\...\Parkalot.Library\App.config(5):
 - <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
C:\...\Parkalot.Library\Visual Studio\App.config(5):
 - <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
C:\...\Parkalot.Entity\App.config(5):
 - <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
C:\...\Parkalot.Entity\Visual Studio\App.config(5):
 - <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
C:\...\Parkalot.Database\App.config(8):
 - <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
C:\...\Parkalot.Business\App.config(5):
 - <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
C:\...\Parkalot.Business\Visual Studio\App.config(5):
 - <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
C:\...\Parkalot.Configuration\App.config(5):
 - <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
C:\...\Parkalot.Test\App.config(5):
 - <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
C:\...\Parkalot.WebFormsClient\Web.config(9):
 - <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
C:\...\Parkalot.Mvc4AspxClient\Web.config(9):
 - <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
C:\...\Parkalot.Mvc4RazorClient\Web.config(9):
 - <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error

```
Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Parkalot.Entity.Tenant'. Could not load file or assembly
'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or 
one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the 
assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Possible cause for this error could be EF version. And you have upgraded from VS2010, seems like solution still searching for the specified version of the assembly above, but actually VS2012 uses different version. EF5 runs on .Net framework 4.5.

1. Expand References and check the EF version.
2. Check the upgrade log for any errors, warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and solved it by deleting the files from the \bin directories.